# Transform tuple shape

Tags: python, for-loop, data-objects

I'm attempting to run a loop faster by using the code to below to create a tuple quickly but can't iterate through the tuple

```
import pandas as pd
Channel = pd.DataFrame()

for row in Channel.itertuples():
     contents = Channel['ID'],Channel['Content']
print(contents)
out: (1,2,3,4,5,'test1','test2','test3','test4','test5')

print(len(contents))
out: 2
```

I would like to transform this tuple to an tuple of length 5 such as ((1,'test1'),(2,'test2'),(3,'test3'),(4,'test4'),(5,'test5')) without looping through each row in Channel DataFrame.

Comment: Why doesn't the loop use `row`?

Comment: There is something fishy here. If `contents` is `(1,2,3,4,5,'test1','test2','test3','test4','test5')`, then `len(contents)` is not `2`.

Comment: This code can't be creating that output. You're overwriting `contents` each time through the loop. You're not using the tuples for anything.